Dig AAAA and traceroute6 resolve to different addresses?
I'm not an expert in DNS or IPv6, but I'm trying to migrate our www site to new hosting. The old one had A and AAAA records that I have updated (and checked that ipv6 is enabled and responds in the new host)
Now the situation is, that ipv4 pings and http go to the new site, but ipv6 still goes to old one.
I'm debugging the situation, and weirdly dig our.domain AAAA gives the correct address and traceroute6 our.domain immediately returns the old ipv6
how is that possible? should i just wait for the propagation, or is there something wrong?
browsers seem to prefer IPv6 so things are a bit whacky now when different protocols point to different hosts

dig asks the DNS server – it's written specifically to talk to a DNS server and nothing else. But traceroute asks your OS, which might get it from many other sources besides the DNS server.
For example, the OS might look in /etc/hosts, or use its internal DNS cache – Linux may have systemd-resolved or nscd as its DNS cache – or (in rare situations) be set up to query NIS or LDAP. (See the /etc/nsswitch.conf file.)
And when both tools query DNS according to /etc/resolv.conf, they might choose the DNS server in a different order (first vs random). If you have the kind of setup where someone's put 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8 into the DNS settings, for example, then different cached data will be seen.

Wait for old cached data to expire. That's the easiest option, unless you're in a hurry. If you changed AAAA records only, then the TTL of your previous AAAA record defines how long it'll remain cached (at maximum).
If you switched the whole nameservers, then the TTL of your previous delegation NS records is what matters (this is often set to 2 days).

Look at the bottom of your dig output to see which server it has queried. Look at your resolv.conf and run dig against each of those servers individually, to see if they all return the same results.

If your nsswitch.conf has the resolve module, then run resolvectl to see what DNS servers are defined there. Run dig against them as well. Also use resolvectl to flush the local cache.



thanks a lot for a detailed explanation and tips for the future! We did not switch nameservers, and it took exactly the TTL of AAAA-record to apply. It was funny that A-record change seemed to apply instantly even though it had same TTL

@tonsteri Most likely the A record was not cached, while the AAAA record was. Which is the real difference between understanding it as "caching" versus "propagation" – DNS primarily uses caching [outside of your own nameservers], and the TTL applies only to cached data; if there's nothing cached then the resolver will query the authoritative data directly, so it will see that update immediately. (Real propagation only happens among your nameservers, where it is usually set up to be near-instant, but in the past the SOA 'Refresh' value used to control it.)
